# onAnimationRepeat() never getting called

Tags: android, kotlin, android-animation

I am using view animations in my app. Here is the anim file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <scale
        android:duration="1500"
        android:fromXScale="1.0"
        android:fromYScale="1.0"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:repeatCount="infinite"
        android:toXScale="7.0"
        android:toYScale="7.0"
        />

    <alpha
        android:duration="600"
        android:fromAlpha="1.0"
        android:repeatCount="infinite"
        android:startOffset="900"
        android:toAlpha="0.0" />
</set>
```

The following is the kotlin code to set the animation on view.

```
    val connectingAnimationWave1 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(activity, R.anim.anim_otp_wave_1)

    connectingAnimationWave1.repeatCount = Animation.INFINITE
    connectingAnimationWave1.repeatMode = Animation.INFINITE


    connectingAnimationWave1.setAnimationListener(object : Animation.AnimationListener{
        override fun onAnimationRepeat(p0: Animation?) {
            Log.d("MyAnimListener", "Repeat "+ p0!!.startOffset)
        }

        override fun onAnimationEnd(p0: Animation?) {
            Log.d("MyAnimListener", "End "+ p0!!.startOffset)
        }

        override fun onAnimationStart(p0: Animation?) {
            Log.d("MyAnimListener", "Start "+ p0!!.startOffset)
        }

    })

    view_wave_1.animation = (connectingAnimationWave1)
```

The issue is that I am not getting the `onAnimationRepeat()` is never getting called. Only `onAnimationStart()` is getting called. Also if I run a thread for 5 seconds and then clear the animation then `onAnimationEnd()` is also getting called. Just `onAnimationRepeat()` is never being called.

Comment: Please add onnectingAnimationWave1.setRepeatMode(Animation.INFINITE);

Comment: @UmeshAHIR Still not working